# Usage of phrase with “of”

Tags: phrase-usage

> My wife’s fear of spider

If I say the phrase below instead of the one above by making propositional phrase with “ of” would it means the same or would it means “fear of my wife’s spider. I thought it has two meaning. Such propositional phrase confuses me.

> Fear of spider of my wife

Comment: The second (but both with spider***s***) could mean that *you* fear the spider that belongs to your wife... It is less natural, but sometimes the phrasing of multiple possessives can be simplified that way. The first sentence is clear.

Comment: **My wife's fear of spiders**, with an s. Which means: **The fear of spiders of my wife**. [fear of countable noun versus fear of uncountable noun].

Comment: No. It should be "My wife's fear of spiders" - we use the plural of spider to mean all spiders in general.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the phrase *the fear of spiders of my wife* is ambiguous.  It might refer to your wife's fear, or someone else's fear of your wife's spiders.

Realistically, this phrase would be rarely or never used. If we wanted to communicate the first message, we'd most likely say, *my wife's fear of spiders*. For the second meaning, we might say, *the fear of my wife's spiders* or *the fear of the spiders that belong to my wife*.

Comment: The OP said: fear of spider, singular. That is a mistake. My wife's fear of spiders.=The fear of my wife of spiders. Which is awkward but grammatical.